# How to overcome a vector memory exhausted error when appending a list of large data.tables in R?

Tags: r, foreach, data.table

I am trying to append 68 `data.tables` each saved on its own `Rdta` file. The size of those 68 files total 1.57GB. All `data.tables`, although each containing different data (but the same column names and order), share the same name: combined.data.

In a fresh session on a Macbook (8GB of RAM memory) I am getting the following error message: `Error: vector memory exhausted (limit reached?) Execution halted`. Would appreciate very much any suggestion about how to lower the memory footprint of the following script:

```
Sys.setenv('R_MAX_VSIZE'=40000000000)

library("foreach")
library("data.table")

file_list <- list.files("/Volumes/LaCie/FannieMae", pattern=glob2rx("Combined_*Rda"), full.names=TRUE)

Combined_Data <- foreach(k = 1:68, .inorder=FALSE, .packages=c("data.table")) %do% {
                          load(file_list[k])
                          return(Combined_Data)
}

Combined_Data <- rbindlist(Combined_Data, fill=TRUE) # Errors
save(Combined_Data, file = "/Volumes/LaCie/FannieMae/Slice.Rda")
```

Thank you!

Comment: I had this kind of problem and saving my data.frames with feather (see https://blog.rstudio.com/2016/03/29/feather/) instead of Rdata or rds objects really helped

Comment: Why are you not using `saveRDS`? How have you called `save`? Note that `save` uses compression by default. You should check the content of the workspace after calling `load` (maybe you need to `rm` some objects). But it could be that the uncompressed data is simply too big for your machine. Personally, I'd use `fwrite`/`fread` instead and save as text files.